# Gradle: get actual snapshot file name of dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, snapshot

I am using SnapShot in my project:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', name: 'xxx', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT', ext: 'zip'
}
```

And here is the dependency info in pom file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xx.xx.xx.xx</groupId>
   <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I get the actual snapshot file name instead of `1.0-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Is the pom a generated pom when you publish from gradle to a mvn repo? What plugin are you using `maven` or `maven-publish`?

Comment: Yes. I am using maven plugin.

Comment: CAn you explain better this sentence "How can I get the actual snapshot file name instead of 1.0-SNAPSHOT?"

Comment: The snapshot archive file name is `xx-1.0-20160218.022830-36.zip` on the server. I want to get this name in the pom file publish to repo, so I can know which snapshot I am using to build my project. @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @Sanster FOr my experience you can't do it and it is the real purpose of snapshot. You can push snapshot with the same version but you will be able to get only the last.

Comment: Thank you! @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 1):

Here is my practice：

```
configurations.each {
  Set<ResolvedArtifact> resolvedArtifacts = it.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts()
  resolvedArtifacts.each { resolvedArtifact ->
  ModuleVersionIdentifier mvi = resolvedArtifact.getModuleVersion().getId()
  def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
  dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', mvi.getGroup())
  dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', mvi.getName())
  dependencyNode.appendNode('version', getRealVersion(resolvedArtifact.getFile().getName(),mvi.getName()))
  }
}

ext.getRealVersion = { fileNameWithVersion, fineName ->
  def real_version = fileNameWithVersion.substring(fineName.length()+1, fileNameWithVersion.length())
  real_version = real_version.substring(0, real_version.length()-4)
  return real_version
}
```